# How to show a "Yes" for a negative occurrence and "No" for a positive occurrence

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, user-expectation

I am working on an internal admin dashboard for a finance company and the PEP (Politically Exposed Person) section of a business is actually a negative thing because those are the people we do not want to do business with. It's also a very important deciding factor when scanning business details, so it needs to be called out. We really can't drastically change the front end at this point. How do we show Yes to this?

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to do business with those people could you not just hide those users entirely?

Comment: Those information may change.

Comment: I think its good enough as it is, except it seems to me that `Yes` should be red, and `No` should be green.

Comment: @ThomasHirsch: That would be inaccessible to red/green color-blind people.

Comment: @SNag would it?  You're saying the words "yes" and "no" are inaccessible to red/green colour-blindness?  It's already red/green, making it green/red would have no difference to colour-blindness (please correct me if I'm wrong on this and accept my apologies)

Comment: I really like the accepted answer below, but if anyone is looking for something simpler what about "Exposed" and "Safe" instead of "No" and "Yes"?

Comment: @freedomn-m: According to what ThomasHirsch said, even if `Yes` is made red and `No` green, red/green color-blind people wouldn't be able to perceive the warning that `PEP: Yes` is trying to convey and the problem in the OP's question would remain for the color-blind.

Comment: For anyone wondering - there are many financial regulations around doing business with people who are actually entrusted with political office or have strong political ties/responsibilities. The term is an internationally recognized concept and these restrictions exist in most countries worldwide.

Comment: What would possess you to make the "yes" green and the "no" red? That seems like either a mental stuck place, or not making an effort.  As far as colorblind people, they're used to having to work a little harder to read data.  After all, they drove to work.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Your objective is to draw your client's attention towards **not doing business with PEP**, therefore you could highlight just that and avoid the opposite sounding `PEP: Yes/No` combination. Leaving the non-PEP blank conveys the required message.

[image: PEP]

Alternate design for PEP:

[image: PEP alternate]

**Update**:
You could explicitly show an indication for non-PEP as well:

[image: Verified non-PEP]

Alternate designs for non-PEP:

[image: Verified non-PEP alternate]

Comment: I'd go with a plain checkmark. Less noise.

Comment: @user76284 Agreed. No need for a graphic even, as there are [several check characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=check) defined within Unicode. Example: ✅ (WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK) or ☑  (BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK). And for the negative situation, perhaps: ❌ (CROSS MARK). And by the way, there is also a character for the triangle-with-exclamation: ⚠  (WARNING SIGN). And: ⚡ (HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN).

Comment: @OluwatobiMayowa In that context, it may be better to also specifically mark the not yet assessed (say, with a question mark icon)

Comment: @OluwatobiMayowa If the state is _not processed yet_, you might want to add something like a clock, loading timer icon or a question mark to indicate that the state is pending and therefore unknown.